# Hero card button with Action type as Open url doesn't work on all skype clients

Tags: botframework, skypedeveloper, skype-bots

I have a very standard code picked up from the GitHub examples like this:

```cs
HeroCard postAnalysisCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
    {
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Show me previous polls", value: "showprevious"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Show me more statistics regarding this question", value: "ShowStats"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Show me more about this topic", value: "http://bing.com/search?q=" + question.Substring(0, queryIndex)),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Help", value: "Help")
    }
};
```

But the `OpenUrl` action doesn't seem to work on all Skype clients. It works on Windows desktop but not on Android.

Is this a known issue? 
If yes, what is the workaround to have a consistent behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue was unescaped special characters in the url. Escaping the string solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provide in `OpenUrl` must use `https://`. Skype requires all external links to be secure.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work on the client version 7.40.0.x. And on mobile versions the button doesn't even show up. Ex: Skype for life 1.0.76.x